# jQuery Selectors and different kind of href links - adding correct CSS classes for links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML file, which includes multiple different type of "a" tags with only href attribute.

The task is to add a correct CSS class for different "a" tags. For example, if link has a suffix .zip, it gets a CSS class "external". With suffix .pdf "a" tag gets a CSS class "pdf". Other external and internal links gets a CSS class "external".

It works correctly.. almost. The problem are links which doesn't have a clear suffix (".html", ".zip") or prefix ("http://", "www.", "../").

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href$='.pdf']").addClass("pdf");
  $("a[href*='.htm'], a[href^='www.'], a[href^=http], a[href*='://']").addClass("external");
  $("a[href]").not("a[href$='.pdf']").not("a[href*='.htm']").not("a[href$='/']").not("a[href*='www']").addClass("download");
});
```

```css
.pdf {
    font-weight:900;
    color: black;
}

.external {
    font-weight:900;
    color: green;
}

.download {
    font-weight:900;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li>
<!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="ticket.pdf">my flight ticket</a></li>
<!-- CLASS PDF -->
<li><a href="backup/2019.zip">my backup.zip</a></li>
<!-- CLASS DOWNLOAD -->
<li><a href="http://randommm.com/file.exe">download exe file</a></li>
<!-- CLASS DOWNLOAD -->
<li><a href="my/normal">my/normal</a></li>
<!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="/normal">/normal</a></li>
<!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="test.htm">test.htm</a></li>
<!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="mysite.com">mysite.com</a></li>
<!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="/mysite">/mysite</a></li>
<!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
```

with a results:

As you can see, internal and external links which doesn't direct to files, gets a wrong CSS class because the last row in my code.

[image]

What I tried was pick a tags with `$("a[href^='/'])` but this didn't give any results.

**Note: Link address can be anything**, so I can't use selector to find a specific link by it's name.
Also, which I didn't remember to write, **downloadable file type can also be anything** but file "pdf" has own class "pdf".

Comment: You could let any non-file URL end with `/`.

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: Your download gets an external it seems

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! I edited your reprex with my CSS what I'm using. If that's okay?

Comment: Sure. It just does not show the icons so give them a color here.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work most reliably you will need to detect the `.pdf` links and all the download links; which means you will need to maintain a list of all valid download file extensions. Anything which does not then meet either of these criteria will be an 'external' link.

You can then detect the file extensions using regular expressions in a function you provide to `addClass()`. The logic of that would look something like this:

```js
$('a').addClass(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if (/\.pdf$/.test(href))
    return 'pdf';
    
  if (/(\.zip|\.exe)$/.test(href))
    return'download';
  
  return 'external';
});
```

```css
.pdf { color: #C00; }
.download { color: #0C0; }
.external { color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="ticket.pdf">my flight ticket</a></li> <!-- CLASS PDF -->
<li><a href="backup/2019.zip">my backup.zip</a></li> <!-- CLASS DOWNLOAD -->
<li><a href="http://randommm.com/file.exe">download exe file</a></li> <!-- CLASS DOWNLOAD -->
<li><a href="my/normal">my/normal</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="/normal">/normal</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="test.htm">test.htm</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="mysite.com">mysite.com</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="/mysite">/mysite</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner than my answer :-D

Comment: Thanks you for the example!
What I didn't remember to mention: what if the link which needs to get a CSS class "download" could be a random filetype? For example it can be `.7zip`, `docx`, ...
(I'll add this information on description)

Comment: Didnt know you could run functions inside addclass

Comment: @markspl_ that's what I meant in the answer by 'you'll need to manually maintain a list of downloadable file extensions'.

Comment: @Stender there's quite a few jQuery methods which accept functions. It's a very useful pattern which avoids having to create explicit loops

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It would be great if I could manually maintain a list of download file types, but problem is I know only that every file link needs to have a class "download" except ".pdf" and ".html" files. And other links (internal/external) gets class "external".
Sorry about confusing/badly written question!

Comment: For the logic to work you need to either know the file extensions to show the download class on, or you need to know all external URLs. As you can see the latter is not a workable solution at all.

Comment: so basically : `var ext = $(this).attr('href').split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','All fileformats here except pdf and html']) == -1){` ? - and then use an array of fileformats like this : https://gist.github.com/raphael-riel/1253986

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach - But basicaly does the same.

In this i go through each link, and checks if it contains your variables , PDF, Zip, EXE etc. you can add as many as you want - If it does not contain any of these, you add the external class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var allLinks = $("a[href]");
  allLinks.each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(".pdf")  >= 0){
 $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').addClass('pdf')
    } else if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(".zip")  >= 0 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf(".exe")  >= 0){
     $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').addClass('download');
    } else {
     $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').addClass('external');
    }
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() +" Class = "+$(this).attr('class') );
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="ticket.pdf">my flight ticket</a></li> <!-- CLASS PDF -->
<li><a href="backup/2019.zip">my backup.zip</a></li> <!-- CLASS DOWNLOAD -->
<li><a href="http://randommm.com/file.exe">download exe file</a></li> <!-- CLASS DOWNLOAD -->
<li><a href="my/normal">my/normal</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="/normal">/normal</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="test.htm">test.htm</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="mysite.com">mysite.com</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
<li><a href="/mysite">/mysite</a></li> <!-- CLASS EXTERNAL -->
```